# Efficient Allocation Of Crafting Resources

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I’m working on a game where you craft various items. There are limited resources, and I need to calculate the maximum times each item can be made based on what’s available. I have everything working except the last part of the algorithm.

First, let’s imagine we’re calculating the max amount of carrots we can grow. There are multiple steps in the recipe to grow 1 carrot:

> Carrot: Consume 1 Water, Use 1 Farm Plot
>
> Water: Use 1 Bucket, Use 1 Pond
>
> Bucket: Consume 7 Wood
>
> Farm Plot: Consume 2 Wood, Consume 1 Soil
>
> Soil: Use 1 Shovel, Use 1 Dirt Pit
>
> Shovel: Consume 2 Wood

If this isn’t clear: to grow carrots we add a bucket of water to a farm plot. To acquire water we use a bucket on a pond. Each bucket is made out of 7 pieces of wood. Each farm plot is made out of two pieces of wood and 1 soil…. etc. If we “consume” an item, all of its uses are immediately depleted. However, if an item is “used”, it only loses 1 use during production. For example, a farm plot can be used 4 times to grow carrots before being destroyed. Let’s say the items have the following uses:

> Carrot: 1 use
>
> Water: 1 use
>
> Bucket: 15 uses
>
> Farm Plot: 4 uses
>
> Soil: 1 use
>
> Shovel: 20 uses
>
> Wood: 1 use

So, here’s where I’m stuck: notice that multiple parts of the recipe require wood. For sake of simplicity, let’s imagine there are 100 pieces of wood we can take. I need a way to calculate how much wood should be allocated to each part of the recipe. Currently, I’m doing it like this: (woodUsesInStep / totalWoodUses) * amountOfWood. So, if we’re looking at how much wood the bucket gets it would be: (7 / 11) * 100 = ~64 pieces of wood. The problem is this won’t produce the highest amount of carrots….

Using this algorithm, I get these results:

> Bucket: 64 wood allocated, 9 buckets made
>
> Shovel: 18 wood allocated, 9 shovels made
>
> Farm Plot: 18 wood allocated, 9 farm plots made
>
> Final Result: 36 carrots can be made

But here are the results I want:

> Bucket: 49 wood, 7 buckets made
>
> Shovel: 4 Wood, 2 shovels made
>
> Farm Plot: 46 Wood, 23 farm plots made
>
> Final Result: 92 carrots can be made

Somehow, I need to identify which part of the recipe produces higher results and allocate the wood based on that, but I'm currently stumped on how to go about it.

Comment: That sounds a little like what we called [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) in a prior millennium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already discovered, your current formula uses the cost of each resource ("ingredient") in the recipe to calculate how to make an equal number of each ingredient. (You can make 9 buckets, 9 shovels, and 9 farm plots with 100 total wood.) It does not take into account the value of each ingredient, that is, (1) how much of each ingredient is required by the recipe and (2) how many times can the ingredient be used before it is consumed.

You already determined this by hand, and you probably followed steps similar to the following. You already know the three ingredients that consume wood are the bucket, shovel, and farm plot. To determine how they should be weighted in your formula, you need to determine how many of each ingredient is consumed for each carrot. You'll need to do this recursively since some of the ingredients are crafted using other ingredients.

When you calculate how many are required, remember that some of the ingredients can be used multiple times, so you may not consume the entire ingredient. For example, if you need 1 bucket but the bucket has 15 uses, you're actually consuming 1/15 of a bucket. If this fraction is confusing, consider 100 carrots. If you need to use a bucket 100 times for 100 carrots and a bucket can be used 15 times before it is consumed (then you need to build better buckets!), you need 100/15 buckets, or 6 2/3 buckets. This is the same as saying each carrot consumes 1/15 of a bucket since 1/15 * 100 = 6 2/3.

```
1 Carrot requires:
1 Water/1 use = 1 Water
1 Farm Plot/4 uses = 1/4 Farm Plot

*** First recursion ***

1 Water requires:
1 Bucket/15 uses = 1/15 Bucket
1 Pond (not applicable to this calculation)

1 Farm Plot requires:
2 Wood/1 use = 2 Wood
1 Soil/1 use = 1 Soil

*** Second recursion ***

1 Bucket requires:
7 Wood/1 use = 7 Wood

1 Soil requires:
1 Shovel/20 uses = 1/20 Shovel
1 Dirt Pit (not applicable to this calculation)

*** Unwinding the recursion ***

*** First recursion ***

1 Water requires:
1/15 Bucket

1 Farm Plot requires:
2 Wood
1 Soil -> 1/20 Shovel

*** Initial ***

1 Carrot requires:
1 Water -> 1/15 Bucket
1/4 Farm Plot -> 1 Farm Plot = {2 Wood + 1/20 Shovel} -> 1/4 * (2 Wood + 1/20 Shovel ) -> 1/2 Wood + 1/80 Shovel
```

---

So 1 Carrot requires:

```
1/15 Bucket (1 Bucket = 7 Wood, so 1/15 Bucket = 7/15 Wood)
1/4 Farm Plot (1 Farm Plot = 2 Wood, so 1/4 Farm Plot = 2/4 or 1/2 Wood)
1/80 Shovel (1 Shovel = 2 Wood, so 1/80 Shovel = 1/40 Wood)
```

Now let's go back to your original formula, i.e. woodUsesInStep / totalWoodUses * amountOfWood. For the Bucket, you used the values of 7 for woodUsesInStep and 11 for totalWoodUses, but now you can see that the woodUsesInStep is actually 7/15 for the Bucket, 1/2 for the Farm Plot, and 1/40 for the Shovel, which means totalWoodUses is 119/120 (7/15 + 1/2 + 1/40).

Now we can apply the formula:

```
Bucket: (7/15) / (119/120) * 100 = 47.1 Wood (makes 6.7 Buckets)
Farm Plot: (1/2) / (119/120) * 100 = 50.4 Wood (makes 25.2 Farm Plots *assuming you have enough Shovels!*)
Shovel: (1/40) / (119/120) * 100 = 2.5 Wood (makes 1.25 Shovels)
```

As you can see when you compare it to your expected results, this gets you pretty close. In fact this does give you the correct distribution of wood in the recipe, but unfortunately this is only the first half of the problem. Since you can't spend 2.5 Wood or make 1.25 shovels, you need a way to determine whether to round up or down for each ingredient. I don't have an exact formula for this part, but I believe this will get you extremely close:

1. Start with the ingredient that you'll be making the fewest of. (In this case, it's the Shovel).
2. Round up to the nearest whole number of ingredients and subtract the cost from your total available resources. (In this case you round 1.25 up to 2 whole Shovels and subtract the cost of 4 Wood from the total of 100 leaving 96 available.
3. Repeat these steps for each ingredient until you run out of resources:
4. The next ingredient is the Bucket since you want to make 6.7 of them versus 25.2 Farm Plots.
5. Round up to 7 Buckets and subtract the cost of 49 Wood from the remaining 96 Wood leaving 47 available.
6. The next (and last) ingredient is the Farm Plot. You'd like to round the 25.2 up to 26, but you only have enough resources for 23, so make those.

Results:

```
2 Shovels
7 Buckets
23 Farm Plots
92 Carrots, as expected
```

Success!

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I've read your reply about a dozen times and it's starting to sink in. I'm going to start translating this into code. It may be a while before I finish, but I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Great! Let me know if you get stuck or need more help.

Comment: So, I have good news and bad news. The good news is I implemented the steps and it passes all my test cases except one. The bad news is I’m not sure what the issue is. Here’s where it fails:

Let’s say we’re producing milk with a cow. This introduces a new step where we feed the cow a carrot and extract milk by using a bucket:
Milk: Use 1 Bucket, Consume 1 Carrot, Use 1 Cow

All other steps and numbers are the same as before, but here are the results I get:
1 Shovel
8 Buckets
18 Farm Plots
60 Milks

But the optimal results should be:
1 Shovel
10 Farm Plots
11 Buckets
120 Milks

Comment: I think this has something to do with the bucket needing 14/15 wood instead of 7/15. I checked the numbers and I think they’re correct in relation to your post. Just to be safe, here are the percentages of wood each resource is being allocated:
Shovel: 0.0171428565
Farm Plot: 0.342857122
Bucket: 0.640000045

Comment: Ok, I've got it to 112 Milks. The problem was that this test case says that when you produce 1 batch of carrots you actually get 3 so I had to factor that in. Now the issue is that both the Farm Plot and Bucket want to be made 11 times... so when I sort the list from smallest to largest and allocate, the farm plot gets priority when it should be the bucket. I'm not sure this problem can be solved though... unless there's a more precise way to order the items when allocating the wood.

Comment: @Michael Just saw your comments. Glad you've made progress. It sounds like you've gotten to the point where you've implemented the formula correctly and the results differ from the desired solution as a result of how you deal with the fractions. I'm not sure at the moment how to determine a formula or algorithm that will calculate the optimal results 100% of the time. One approach would be to calculate all the possibilities (after applying the main formula) and choose the one that produces the most.

Comment: @Michael Also, if you haven't already tried doing so, try adjusting the way you sort the list in the last step to see if it makes a difference. For example, you could sort by which ingredient you'll be making the fewest of, or by which ingredient requires the fewest resources to make, or by which ingredient will consume the fewest resources total. I'm not convinced that any order will work 100% of the time, though.

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is a way to get a 100% perfect calculation of this without brute forcing a simulation (which I was doing previously). I'm fine with this being within a small margin of error, though it would be nice to get it perfect. I tried rounding up or down instead of always rounding up and it gave me the correct Milk results... but then that threw off the other calculations. I'll try sorting it some different ways! Thanks again for all the help!